# Can a Xamarin-android application be updated to native java android application?

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have an apk generate by xamarin android.I am trying to update that application using another apk generated from android studio(java).

Is it possible to update.
 1. Using PlayStore.
 2. OR Without Playstore.

It will be helpful if someone can explain about updating apk's and regulations from different platforms. I am not able to find any source for this kind of update. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the package name and the certificate you use to sign is the same, the actual code in the APK doesn't matter. You could have an app, first created in unity, then updated with Xamarin, then Java and update it without issues, as long as you have the certificate and package.

So basically, as long as you use the same package name and certificate, you can update it even if it's running on a different framework/language/engine